# Magento 2 Grouped Products AND Google Shopping Ads/Merchant Center

Tags: magento2.4, google-shopping

I'm sure this has been discussed before by any Magento shop managers/owners who use Grouped products and are trying to get their products added to Google Shopping. It's been a nightmare for us, as Google Merchant Center doesn't seem to like Grouped products.

This is Magento CE 2.4.3

We are using a couple of extensions, one by Amasty for the rich snippet code and one from Magmodules for the product feed that gets sent to Merchant center. We have roughly 900 products in our feed. In 99% of all cases, there are two simple products tied to each grouped product. The difference being condition (new vs. used) and the price for each. In more than half the situations, one of the versions is not in stock. In situations where one of the versions is not available, we don't display the price of the out of stock version, we have a link to contact us to inquire about availability and pricing. Sounds good so far, right?

Apparently, Google doesn't like the fact that the product feed we send over only has one price included in the XML, while the source code of the product page has two prices, and the product page only displays one. So they disapprove all products where that is the case. I've tried working with Magmodules but they don't seem to know exactly what to do. They are now suggesting we remove the second rich snippet for the product that is not available. Well, that's not easily achieved without some custom development. And I don't want to invest in a project like that without knowing for certain that it's going solve the issue.

I've reached out to Amasty to see if they have a way to do that with their plugin. But I need to figure out what others have found to get M2 Grouped products working in Merchant Center. We run into issue after issue, and it seems like if we just used a different type of product configuration that it wouldn't be so problematic. But that's a massive undertaking when you have thousands of products.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Include product specs from both products (new and used/refurbished) in rich snippet. Include both variants in your XML-feed. That should be enough to prevent Google to disapprove your products.